# Should my HTML, CSS and Javascript be together or separate?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Very new to the world of HTML and I will try to phrase this question as best as I can.

Currently, I am creating a website. For each page I am creating, I have 2/3 pages - 1 I save the HTML file in, the other I save the file .css/.js.I make sure to keep the name of the file the same and in turn, it edits my html page as I wish it to do. So I therefore have a folder with 2/3 files made up of HTML, CSS and Javascript. Is this the correct way, or should I have everything saved together in a .html file?

Comment: There is reason why they are separately called `JavaScript`, `HTML` and `CSS` rather than just `HTML`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_JavaScript So yes, you should separate them.

Comment: As a note: _java_  and _javascript_ are two completely different things.

Comment: Separating them makes it easier to code and debug, because you don't have to go through a gigantic file. It also makes you create modular code, which is a good practice. So, unless the chunk of code is really small, it is a better practice to keep them separate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032329/should-all-javascript-go-into-a-separate-js-file

Comment: Separating html, CSS, JavaScript code makes your code more maintainable. Also separating them is the best practice in the industry.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: @Paulie_D Maybe we should also specify where this question could be more appropriate? This would be more constructive and helpful compared to just closing the question (although in this occasion, I am not sure this question is too broad or opinion based, but that's not important)

Comment: The OP asks "should".... While the answer may be obvious it is most definitely asking for opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Reasons for separation:

1. Separate JS - Reuse it on other pages
2. Separate CSS - Able to give the site a new fresh look easily along with reuse
3. Separate HTML - Focus on content not look.

Also should be mentioned CSS/JS could be cached if used on multiple pages on your site

Answer (score -1):

First and main rule :

> A web developer should be able to change the markup in an HTML
>   template without worrying about accidentally breaking a CSS rule or
>   some JavaScript functionality.

So Yes, your `html`, `css`, `js` files should be separate.

Comment: That looks like a quote from somewhere. Please include the source where you quoted the quote.