# Bind Bootstrap3 datetimepicker with ASP.NET Core model value

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm trying to bind the [Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) to to my ASP.NET Core model using the MVC tag helper like this:

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input asp-for="Observation.ObservationDateTime" type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I am hitting a problem initialising the control.  The following does not work:

1) in the Razor section scripts like this:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
}
```

Doing this initialises the datetimepicker, **but without the model value**.  How do I get it to work but with the model value as the initial value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include your date field in the view like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "my-date" } })
```

And initialize it in your JavaScript like this (I am using jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // get date from MyDate input field
    var date = $(".my-date").val();

   // use current date as default, if input is empty
   if (!date) {
       date = new Date();
   }

    $('.my-date').datetimepicker({
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
        date: date
    });
});
```

Please note that I am using 'my-date' class as input selector, you may want to select it differently... and obviously you need to include the the bootstrap library...

As a side note, it is best practice to put your script in an external file: [why should I avoid inline Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032329/should-all-javascript-go-into-a-separate-js-file)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it still is not displayinf the model value.  In the browser there is an error message: 'unexpected value'.

Comment: I have update my answer... in java script you can read the value from your input and pass it datatimepicker. this should display the date from the model.