# Display User Birthday from Database in DateTimePicker using AJAX in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I want to display in DateTimePicker user birthday from database using AJAX/jQuery in ASP.NET CORE 2.1 project.Here is my primary view:

```
<input type="date" asp-for="@Model.DateOfBirth" id="dateOfBirth"    class="form-control" name="DateOfBirth" value="@Model.DateOfBirth" />
```

And here is my property:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:dd\/MM\/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

I have controller Account with action Profile:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Profile()
    {
        var user =await this.userManager.GetUserAsync(this.User);
        if (user == null) {

            await this.signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        }
        var model = Mapper.Map<ProfileViewModel>(user);

        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), Include your date field in the view like this:

```
 <input type="text" asp-for="DateOfBirth" id="dateOfBirth" class="form-control my-date" />
```

in the section scripts like this:

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var date = $(".my-date").val();
        $('.my-date').datetimepicker({
            format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
            date: date
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

As a side note, it is best practice to put your script in an external file: [why should I avoid inline Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032329/should-all-javascript-go-into-a-separate-js-file)